# Get json array from php with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want get a json array from PHP with jQuery, but it is not working.

PHP

```
$json[] = array(
  'status' => 'no',
  'xxx' => $myhtml
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

`$myhtml` is HTML source.

jQuery

```
$.post('server.php', {'work' : work , 'view_id' : view_id } , function(data){
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#main-show').html(json.xxx);         
});
```

I have array json in console, but json.xxx is undefined.

Comment: What does it say, when you access server.php via browser? Is JSON data there?

Comment: yes i have JSON data in console browser

Comment: Where's the rest of the jQuery code? Like variables `work` and `view_id`? is jQuery includes correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()`, the `php` code is also modified, i.e.:

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-show"></div>
<script>
    work = "test";
    view_id = "test2";
    $.post('json.php', {'work' : work , 'view_id' : view_id } , function(data){
        var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        $('#main-show').html(json.xxx);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**php:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$myhtml = '<p> TEST </p>';
$json = array(
    'status' => 'no',
    'xxx' => $myhtml
);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an extra outer array.

Your current JSON would look like:

```
[
   {"status" : "no",  "xxx" : "html string"}
]
```

So to access that would need

```
$('#main-show').html(json[0].xxx);
```

But it would probably be easier to change php to:

```
$json = array(
  'status' => 'no',
  'xxx' => $myhtml
);
```

which when json encoded would produce:

```
{"status" : "no",  "xxx" : "html string"}
```